# with (tablock) does not seem to make code faster for insert select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recovery-model

I read about minimal logging and that one should use with (tablock) for `insert select`s. I had high expectations when I added this but it does not seem to make a difference. I use it in ETL and tables are empty (truncated) and the recovery model is "simple".

Am I missing something? I also see `tablockx` sometimes but when I read about minimal logging it mentioned specifically `tablock`.
E.g. here it does not mention `tablockx` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: High expectation on minimal logging or faster inserts? MS-Docs doesn't mention anything about speeding up the operation.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin: What is the benefit of minimal logging them? I want faster code  :-). I mean faster inserts

Comment: Maybe try In Memory tables for fast inserts ?

Comment: @Mo64: If minimal logging is not good for speed then what is it good for?

Comment: As far as _what is miminal logging good for_, from the doc you referenced - _under the simple recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, minimal logging of bulk-import operations reduces the possibility that a bulk-import operation will fill the log space._.  You might also find this post helpful - [Minimal Logging with INSERT…SELECT into Empty Clustered Tables](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-empty-clustered).  Make sure you are meeting all of the prerequisites for minimal logging.

Comment: I think you are confusing two things. This is an old thread but I think still relevant. [How to do very fast inserts to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861944/how-to-do-very-fast-inserts-to-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many rows are you inserting at one time? Despite what the comments say, minimal logging does affect performance, but it's very minute and maybe a moot thing to worry about.

Using the `TABLOCK` query hint moreso helps with large data insert performance because it tells the SQL Optimizer to take a **Table Lock** upfront, as opposed to going through **Lock Escalation** which can be costly at runtime for large batches of data.

Generally without that hint, an insert might cause a bunch of **Row Level Locks** to occur first, and then when the SQL Engine realizes it crossed a certain threshold of **Row Level Locks**, it escalates to a **Table Lock** anyway, which means it wasted it's time spinning it's wheels acquiring **Row Level Locks** to start with. This is why for a large insert of rows, using that hint *can* be helpful.

Typically you need to be inserting at least a certain number of rows (I believe at least 102,400 rows per parallel thread executing the insert) for the `TABLOCK` query hint to be helpful with performance, otherwise it doesn't matter or in some cases can even hinder performance as Erik Darling [wrote up in this interesting article](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/tablock-isnt-always-better/).

Comment: Thanks, I am inserting milions of rows. Maybe because I was expecting a huge effect and got disapointed. What about `TABLOCKX`? Will that be even better?

Comment: @xhr489 I think in your case there's no performance difference between the `TABLOCK` and `TABLOCKX` hints (but would need to refresh myself by researching a little). Honestly YMMV using them. You'd have to look at the **execution plan** to see how many parallel threads (DOP) are being used to serve the query and divide the total number of rows in a single insert by that number to see if you're above the threshold where performance gains are normally seen (102,400 rows per thread). If you compare the same exact insert with and without the table lock hint, do you see any significant difference?

Comment: I have not measured as in an experiment. I will maybe do that. I just added it to some jobs and did not see a huge difference. I have collected the actual execution plan for some of them and the threads are very unevenly distributed with IO. I am actually thinking to add `option (maxdop 1)` because server is very buisy at that time and no need to occupy more than needed.

Comment: @xhr489 I'd recommend being careful when forcing the `MAXDOP` via hints. Your already *slow* insert could turn into a crawl, but you can at least isolate the insert statement itself and test it a few different ways to see what works best. Since you mentioned this is part of a bigger job, you might want to verify the bulk of slowness is the insert itself and not whatever else is happening in the job. If you're able to add the **execution plan(s)** to your original post (pastetheplan.com), we can probably provide your more insight and advice if there are other bottlenecks in your jobs as well

Comment: I am careful :-). I don't know if I am allowed to paste the plan, so I think better safe than sorry. Thanks for help. I will wait to se if others anwer and then accept the best answer.

Comment: @xhr489 No problem! Yea everyone these days is weary about pasting their execution plans, but all they have are the names of the objects referenced in the query itself (and dependent objects), which can easily be obfuscated before uploading the plan. For example, [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/sql-performance/anonymize-your-plans) has a feature built in to automatically anonymize your execution plan, and is a pretty awesome free tool for analyzing execution plans (over the default one in SSMS).